# Value of the double-blank domino?

Tags: dominoes

In the standard [Draw Dominoes](https://www.pagat.com/domino/line/draw.html), is the double-blank domino, if in hand at the end of a round, counted as zero or 14 points?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Nearly [all variations](http://www.domino-games.com/domino-rules/) of Dominos have you count the number of pips on dominos left in a losing player's hand. Since the double blank has zero pips, it is worth zero points.

**Draw Dominos**

> **Scoring** - When a hand ends, the player with the lightest hand (i.e. the fewest number of dots on their dominoes) wins the number of sum total of points in all of his opponents hands (minus the points in his own hand, if any).